How to send recordIds from a listview button to the visualforce page without using StandardController
I want to create a listView button, which basically sends the selected record ids from the list view to the visual force page..
Here is my approach till yet.
I created a list view button of url type :
/apex/DynamicRecordDisplayPage?selectedIds={!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Account)}&objectApiName=Account
Here is my Apex Controller:
    public List<String> selectedIds { get; set; }
    public DynamicRecordDisplayController() {
        // Retrieve the selected IDs from the URL parameters
        String ids = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ids');
        if (ids != null && !String.isBlank(ids)) {
            selectedIds = ids.split(',');
            system.debug('selectedIds '+selectedIds);
        } else {
            selectedIds = new List<String>();
        }
    }   
}

here is my vfPage :
<apex:page controller="DynamicRecordDisplayController">
    <h2>Selected Records</h2>
    <apex:repeat value="{!selectedIds}" var="recordId">
        <p>Record ID: {!recordId}</p>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>

Upon selecting the records and clicking on the list view button. I am only getting the Id prefix of the selected record.
For reference in this example since this listview button is configured on the Account object. No matter which record I select from the list view, after clicking the button. It just outputs:
001
I want to implement this functionality because, there is a requirement in which I would need to basically send do the same for multiple objects, but I want to avoid the overhead for creating the same vfPage for multiple objects. Therefore, I was thinking along the way to implement just a url button for every concerned object.
